# how to set combo value by id?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, combobox

I am trying to set the value of this angular combo with an id:

```
$scope.myColor = 
{
   id: 4
};
```

However it wont work?

this is the rest of the angular js code:

```
 angular.module('selectExample', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
          $scope.colors = [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'black',
            shade: 'dark'
          }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'white',
            shade: 'light'
          }, {
            id: 3,
            name: 'red',
            shade: 'dark'
          }, {
            id: 4,
            name: 'blue',
            shade: 'dark'
          }, {
            id: 5,
            name: 'yellow',
            shade: 'light'
          }];
          //$scope.myColor = $scope.colors[2]; // red

          $scope.myColor = {
            id: 4
          };
        }
      ]);
```

This is a plunkr ref:
http://plnkr.co/edit/jkXl4BhLeuu0CWnMhqkV?p=info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `track by` option to tell Angular what field to use for comparison:

```
  <select ng-model="myColor"
          ng-options="color.name for color in colors track by color.id">
  </select>
```

That should select the proper item in the combo-box.

Answer (score 0):

If I properly get your question you want to show like bellow

```
Currently selected: blue
```

If so, you can just say like this at your 73rd line of plunker.

```
<hr/>Currently selected: {{colors[myColor.id-1].name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i undestood, the $scope.colors is the combo options and Scope.myColor is the combo value. It is right?

To AngularJS, combo works just with the array options. AngularJS will consider tow objects equal just if they are the same object. Does not matter if the objects have same attributes and values.

Your commented line that chose red color, should work.